# Endless RecyclerView - ProgressBar are disappearing only when scrolling slowly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView and fetching objects from an API in batches of ten. For pagination, I use EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener and following this tutorial [Endless RecyclerView.](http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)

My problem: on scrolling programm have to adding progress bar and delete it after data from server fetched. But in my case it doesn't work. ProgressBar still downloading. it desapear if scroll slow. If scroll faster Progress bar aren't disappearing.

[image: Endless RecyclerView]

Method that fetched data

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest(int startList,int endList,final JsonObjectListener listener) {
            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            i = startLsit;
                            while(i < endList) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();

                                  /***** TONS OF CODE  *****/

                                        movieList.add(movie);
                                    }

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                              i++;
                              lastNumber = i;
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listener.onDone(lastNumber);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        }
```

I use method above in fragment:

```
makeJsonObjectRequest(0, 9, new JsonObjectListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDone(int lastNumberI) {
                           lastNumber = lastNumberI;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onError(String error) {

                       }
                   }); }

   mAdapter = new RVAdapter(getContext(),movieList,this,mRecyclerView);
        mAdapter.setClickListener(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                movieList.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(movieList.size()-1);
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        movieList.remove(movieList.size()-1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(movieList.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = lastNumber;
                        int end = start + 9;
                        makeJsonObjectRequest(start, end, new JsonObjectListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDone(int lastNumberI) {
                                lastNumber = lastNumberI;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(String error) {

                            }
                        });
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```

My adapter like this [Endless RecyclerView](http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)

I notice that when I scroll faster code below repeates

```
mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                movieList.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(movieList.size()-1);
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        movieList.remove(movieList.size()-1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(movieList.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = lastNumber;
                        int end = start + 9;
                        makeJsonObjectRequest(start, end, new JsonObjectListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDone(int lastNumberI) {
                                lastNumber = lastNumberI;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(String error) {

                            }
                        });
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: where is your progressDilog in this code?

Comment: Can you post the whole code of `handler.postDelayed(..., ...)`?

Comment: @AmitRanjan you can see it in this link http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html

Comment: Maybe your delay is the problem here. Remove the delay or make it shorter.

Comment: @xdevs23 How it will be? Removing delay? Any idea? I am new in android and java. Thank's

Comment: Instead of `handler.postDelayed(..., 2000)` use `handler.post(...)` or decrease the delay (`2000` is your current delay in milliseconds, which is 2 seconds. 1 sec = 1000 ms)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107109/discussion-between-elaman-aitymbet-and-xdevs23).

Answer (score 0):

Move it outside of the runnable. Otherwise it will be only removed after two seconds (or it won't be at all)

```
mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            movieList.add(null);
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(movieList.size()-1);
            //   remove progress item
            movieList.remove(movieList.size()-1);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(movieList.size());
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //add items one by one
                    int start = lastNumber;
                    int end = start + 9;
                    makeJsonObjectRequest(start, end, new JsonObjectListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDone(int lastNumberI) {
                            lastNumber = lastNumberI;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String error) {

                        }
                    });
                    mAdapter.setLoaded();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: if I  implement  this, the progress bar it will not visible.

Comment: Umm... Why don't you create a progressview outside of the recyclerview? You could just add it to the root view and change visibility when needed. Make sure to bring it to the front. (`.bringToFront()`)